# Stored procedure to count number of occurrences of a value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, count, sql-update

I would like, thanks to a **stored procedure**, to count in test_paternite, the number of occurrences of "parent" in "cb" column (image 1).
For example, the parent "ASPIELEC 01 1/1" appears 1 time in cb column: (image 2)

[image: image 1]

`SELECT cb, parent, test_paternite FROM [database].[dbo].[Paternite] where cb='ASPIELEC 01 1/1'`

[image: image 2]

expected results for ASPIELEC 01 1/1:

[image]

I tried:

```
USE [database]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[INS_MAJ_PATERNITE_V2] 
        @retcode int OUTPUT,
        @message VARCHAR(255) OUTPUT
    AS

BEGIN
    
            ---- how many times parents appears in cb column
    
    WITH nb_parent_dans_cb
    AS
    (
        SELECT count(*) AS nb, cb 
        FROM Paternite
        where parent in (select cb from paternite)
        GROUP BY cb 
    )

    UPDATE Paternite
    SET Test_paternite = nb_parent_dans_cb.nb
    FROM Paternite
    INNER JOIN nb_parent_dans_cb ON paternite.cb = nb_parent_dans_cb.cb

END
```

Is this the best way?

Comment: Please please please use formatted text for data *not images - they are messy, hard to read, and impossible to copy and paste out for people willing to assist. Also, define best? Does you currently solution provide the required results? Is so what are you hoping to improve on?

Comment: Thank you for your advices, I don't know yet how to correctly use stackoverflow

Comment: However, I voted for the right answers for the other questions I asked

Comment: @jess.r But voting isn't the same as "marking an answer". And 6 months after you started using SO, "not knowing" is just a bad excuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you could simplify this as a straight correlated subquery:

```
update p
set test_paternite = (select count(*) from paternite p1 where p1.cb = p.parent)
from paternite p
```

Comment: Thank you the results are those expected (as my query's), but my query affects only 1620 lines while yours affects all the lines of the table, why ?